# How to removeEventListener from a ref element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a video element and it is displayed in the modal when you click on the poster, conventionally it looks like this:

```
const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false)
const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null)

const handleOpenVideo = () => setOpen(true)

. . .

return (
  <>
    <Modal isOpen={isOpen}>
      <video ref={videoRef} src="..." />
    </Modal>
    <s.Poster onClick={handleOpenVideo}>
      <img src"..." />
    </s.Poster>   
  <>
)
```

We need to attach some events (for example loadedmetadata)

We do it this way:

```
. . .

useEffect(() => {
  const handleLoadedMetaData = () => { ... }
    
  videoRef.current?.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', handleLoadedMetaData)
    
  return () => {
    videoRef.current?.removeEventListener('loadedmetadata', handleLoadedMetaData)
  }
}, [isOpen])

. . .
```

There is an interesting point about deleting the event listener; at the time of execution, videoRef.current is null, that is, deleting the handler will not happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to remove from the element you added to, see comments:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleLoadedMetaData = () => { /* ... */ };
    
    // Grab the element as `element`, use that
    const element = videoRef.current;
    element?.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", handleLoadedMetaData);
    
    return () => {
        // ...including here
        element?.removeEventListener("loadedmetadata", handleLoadedMetaData);
    };
}, [isOpen, videoRef.current]); // Make it one of the effect dependencies
```

Also note adding it to the dependencies array. *(I'm assuming `isOpen` is used by `handleLoadedMetaData`.)*

Comment: Why videoRef.current in dependencies?

Mutable values like 'videoRef.current' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component.

Comment: @user3449174 - Because if you don't re-run the effect when `videoRef.current` changes, you won't be hooked into the event on the new element that replaced the old one. (Example: You have code that conditionally renders the `video` element.) If the video element is stable across renders the particular way your component is written, listing it won't change anything, because it won't change and trigger the effect. If it isn't stable, then listing it is necessary to correctly hook the event. Thus: list it. :-)